# How can I resume a tmutil restore?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I need to restore a 200 GB user directory from a Time Machine backup.  However it fails periodical with an error about the source file.  Different file each time.

```
bash-3.2# tmutil restore /Volumes/Tardis/Backups.backupdb/Lothlorien/\
2015-09-12-001849/Users/sherwood/ ~sherwood
Error (-47) (SrcErr:YES) Copying \    
'/Volumes/Tardis/Backups.backupdb/Lothlorien/\
2015-09-12-001849/Users/sherwood/Desktop/@ToBeSorted.aplibrary/\
Masters/2011/04/19/20110419-051328/2009-09-23 at 10-34-21.jpg' \
to '(null)'
Error (-47) (SrcErr:NO) Copying \
'/Volumes/Tardis/Backups.backupdb/Lothlorien/2015-09-12-\
001849/Users/sherwood/Desktop/@ToBeSorted.aplibrary/Masters\
/2011/04/19/20110419-051328/2009-09-23 at 10-33-45.jpg' to \
'/Volumes/Users/sherwood/sherwood/Desktop/@ToBeSorted.aplibrary/Masters\
/2011/04/19/20110419-051328'
Total copied: 58331.73 MB (61165251760 bytes)
Items copied: 38889
```

If I attempt to run tmutil a second time:

```
bash-3.2# tmutil restore -v  \   
/Volumes/Tardis/Backups.backupdb/Lothlorien/2015-09-12-\
001849/Users/sherwood/ /Volumes/User_Raid/\
/Volumes/User_Raid/sherwood: File exists (error 17)
```

Is there a particular syntax, a flag, to resume an interrupted restore?

Hardware:  Mac Pro 3.2 GHz quad core with 24 GB ram,

Software:  Mountain Lion.  tmutil version 2.0.0